# Display unicode character, Android back arrow, in toast message

Tags: android, xml, unicode, android-toast

I'm trying to display this Unicode character in a Toast message:

http://graphemica.com/%E2%AE%8C

It is embedded in a Xml file that contains all the strings of the Android application, like this

```
<string name="back_press">Click again &#11148; to exit</string>
```

The message shown from the Toast is the one in the image

[toast message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx0en.png)

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Unicode character, in your case U+2B8C and replace **U+**  by **1x**, but you should look for another icon because that one doesn't exist, search one you like in [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode).

For this example I've used the back arrow:

```
int unicode = 0x2B05;
String textIcon =  new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your text here" + textIcon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And that should view your icon.   **[image: U+]**

Comment: There is a unicode for the back arrow &#8592; in your example, I'm currently using this in my Xml file and it works. 
I was searching for a way to display that precise character inserting it in directly in the Xml where are there all the strings, not using Java code. However thanks for the contribute, probably there is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: That is the same, just use different string sources and then concat them.
(I don't see unicode character for &#8592 )

Comment: I can see the &#8592; we probably use a different document codification; I also see the characther &#11148; that I'm looking for, Android Studio displays it in the code preview of the xml string like in the image 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBunc.png

I think it is a problem of the Toast codification.

Comment: I think, that character is not supported by Android, all supported icons are in the keyboard (icon button) .
Check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567146/unicode-character-on-android-not-displaying).